# How to make automatic uppercase in column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, uppercase

I want to ask, is it possible to make every insert data in a column will uppercase without update upper(column_name)

Example when I will insert "mango" and then in column, and SQL Server will automatically display "MANGO".

How to make automatic uppercase when I insert lowercase data?

Comment: you can use a trigger. for example see here: https://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/144862-uppercase-trigger

Comment: Why does it "matter"? If it *really* matters, then use a computed column for the display value; then it doesn't matter what someone inserts for the data column, `'manga'`,`'Mango'`,`'mANGO'`,`'MAngo`' or even `'MaNgO'` would all appear as `'MANGO'` in the computed column.

Comment: Quite frankly - DON'T. If your system requires a consistent choice of characters, then you should enforce it with a constraint and let the process that does the insert / update know (via an error) that uppercase is required. Nothing worse than doing something in an application and seeing something different when reviewing afterwards IMO

Comment: Yea don't.  Use UPPER() when you SELECT

Answer (score 2):

And here's how to do this with a trigger.

```
create or alter trigger tg_upper_column_name 
on some_table
after insert,update
as
begin

  set nocount on;

  update some_table
  set column_name = upper(column_name)
  where id in (select id from inserted)
   and column_name <> upper(column_name) collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways to address this problem:

1. Use a trigger to upper case the value.
2. Only allow upper case values in the column, using a check constraint.
3. Use a view or computed column to generate the results you want.

I don't like the first method because triggers complicate databases in general.  However, it might be the best solution.  I don't like the second because you specifically want to insert `'mango'`.

The third suggests a view or computed column.  The view would look like:

```
create view v_t as
    select col1, col2, upper(column_name) as column_name
    from t;
```

Then when you access the view, you see what you want -- although the underlying data is not changed.  You can also do this with a computed column:

```
alter table t add column_name_to_view as (upper(column_name));
```

Comment: I have exist column, not create new column. And I want to make this exist column will uppercase when every insert data, how?